# Can an app connect the mobile/smartphone to an Wifi network without going to Wifi Settings?

Tags: android, ios, wifi, qr-code, android-wifi

Does that work on Andoid and also on iOS?

To explain more, in future I would like to do that:

(1) The app would scan a QR code from a cardboard box. The QR code would contain the name of a Wifi network and such network would be really within reach of the phone (consider that).

(2) The app would connect to such Wifi network automatically, without the need to go to the 'Wifi Settings' of the phone and connect to such network manually. Consider here that the password of such Wifi network is always the same, always the same string. That is, the act of connecting the mobile to such network would be all done in app code. The need of a simple 'yes/no' confirmation for the user would be no problem.

Then, will that be possible?

Comment: There is a [specific framework and entitlement on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/wi-fi_configuration)

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Can that be done on any Android?

Answer (score 1):

Android Q can let you do that.
No sure about iOS.

Comment: Only on Android Q? Can that be done on any Android?